# Can I return a variable inside a function for more than one time?

Tags: python

I have 2 functions `fun_1` and `fun_2`

`fun_1` → loops over `fun_2` and stores the output of it in a variable named `X`.

I want the return value of `fun_1` to be the value of each iteration of the loop, so the return value I need is a tuple of 5 values, each value for `X` in one of the iteration instead of the value of only the last iteration.

Note:`fun_1` and `fun_2` are just examples for functions just to demonstrate the idea and understand it so that I can apply it to complex function.

```
def fun_1():
    N = 0
    while N <= 5:
        X = fun_2()
        N = N+1
    return(X)
```

Comment: What is `fun_2()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like the below?

```
def fun_2():
    return 9
    
def fun_1():
    return tuple(fun_2() for i in range(0,5))
    
print(fun_1())
```

output

```
(9, 9, 9, 9, 9)
```

Comment: Suggest you use the more "pythonic": `fun_2() for _ in range(5)`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered utilizing a list? For example:

```
def fun_1():
    N = 0
    X = []
    while N <= 5: 
        X += [fun_2()] # or X.append(fun_2())   
        N += 1
    return X
```